# Height percentage not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, height

I am trying to use height property using percentages, but it doesn't work. I want to use percentage so it looks fine in any resolution.

```
<div id="bloque_1" style="height: 80%;background: red">   
</div>
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Height percentages are somewhat sloppy, but if you insist, using percentages will only take the percentage of the height of the container. Try adding { min-height: 100%; } to your { body } tag.

Comment: min-height doest work =(. I used instead, height: 100%

Comment: Now you will have an issue when you're content height needs to expand past 100%.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you are using `%` for width, or height, the 1st question you should ask is that `80%` of what? So you also need to apply height to the parent element, so assuming that this element of yours is inside the body tag, you need to use this in your CSS

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

So now your `div` element will be `80%` of `100%`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YteQ3/)

Side Note: Also when you are dealing with `absolute` positioned elements, you may come across a scenario where your `div` won't exceed the current viewport height, so in that case you need to have `min-height`

Comment: I had been fiddling with a similar problem for a while, I had been setting body to 100%, but not html, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Everything outside of `bloque_1` will need a height as well, or you'll get 80% of 0.
You may also have to apply a height of 100% to the `body`.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hFBKu/) that shows it in action.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `100%` height on your parent element

`HTML` code-

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="bloque_1" style="height:80%;background:red;width:100%;">   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`CSS` Part-

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0;background: #3c3c3c }
```

Working Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SEafD/1/

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E6uXF/)

```
html,body{
    height:100%
}
#bloque_1{
    background:red;
    height:80%;
}
```