# div height:100% wrap content

Tags: css, html, height

why is that my div only color based on its content?which is the height of the button from the code below.the div is only wrapping its content.

my div element is

```
<div id="test">
 <button>testing</button?
 </div>
```

and in css

```
#test{
background-color:#666;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

i set the height to 100% but it only colors the height of the element which is button.how can i color the whole height of the site?what would be the best way for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Height Percentage not working css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642866/height-percentage-not-working-css)

Answer (score 1):

To make any element fit for `height:100%`, HTML and body height should be set to 100%

```
body, html{  
  height:100%
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ACiBocI/2/)**

Comment: If you set the height to 100%, what if the content grows more than 100% of the viewport height. The content overflows with no background.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to color the whole site you can apply the css directly to body or html tag.

```
body, html {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:#666;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because the height of the div is occupied by the button.

so always start with below css to cover the browser

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: after i set the height of the body to 100%? i just need to color the whole height of 1 div.

Comment: @KerPPag That is what I tried to say, the child element is inheriting the width of parent.  So `height and width of body == height and width of the div (#text)`  If you want to set color the div then assign it like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/GVZn6/

Comment: thank you i tried it and it works. but if i but if i put it to another the the height of the site gets longer. 
like <div id="test"><div id="test2"><div id="test3"></div></div></div>
if i do the height 100% it gets longer.