# CSS background 100% height - How to do?

Tags: html, css

In css column, how can I make the background 100% of the height, even if content is empty?

I tried `height: 100%;`, `display: block;`, but nothing seems working!

The background (height) fills up till the content height. Then below that it is completely empty! Please check the screenshot attached below:

[image: screenshot]

CSS Code that I am using is as follows:

```
.computer-wrapper{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #7771a0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 600px;
}
.computer-left-column{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #7771a0;
}
.computer-middle-column{
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
.computer-right-column{
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

In HTML side, I am using the following:

```
<!-- left column start -->
<div class="computer-left-column">
    <ul id="treemenu" class="treeview">
        <li>Scripts
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">ASP.NET Scripts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHP Scripts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CMS Modules &amp; Plugins</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Software
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Windows</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Linux</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">MAC</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ddtreemenu.createTree("treemenu", false)
    </script>
</div>
<!-- left column end -->

<!-- middle column start -->
<div class="computer-middle-column">
    Main Content Area
</div>

<!-- middle column end -->

<!-- right column start -->
<div class="computer-right-column">
    Right Sidebar Advertisement Area
</div>
<!-- right column end -->
```

Any suggestion how I can fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Height Percentage not working css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642866/height-percentage-not-working-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set on css `height:100vh;`

```
.computer-middle-column{
    height:100vh;
}
.computer-wrapper{
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8bsLg/5/show/light/)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the help. But the column height is overflowing the wrapper. Any way to keep it inside? See the screenshot: http://oi57.tinypic.com/zx0dol.jpg

Comment: http://demo.expect360.com/ it is the link to the development page. Same code, but here it is exceeding the wrapper, but in fiddle, it is shorter than wrapper.

Comment: Edited my answer and demo link

Answer (score 0):

You could use position absolute with top, and bottom set to 0;

e.g.

```
.computer-middle-column{
    width: 600px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the following css style

background-size:cover;

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to add height:100% to your body and html.

```
body,html{height:100%;}
```

Then, height:100% to your selected div will works.

[like here](http://jsfiddle.net/ngU6b/)

Good Luck!!

**update**

Do you want it to be like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7JfV2/1/)?.

or

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/7JfV2/3/)?

Comment: I wanted like http://jsfiddle.net/7JfV2/3/ . But making `body,html{height:100%;}` and column height 100%, still not working! May be it is a semantic-ui issue that is colliding with the code! :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8bsLg/3/ .Just remove min-height: 600px from your .computer-wrapper and use @Shibin ragh method (using vh).

Answer (score 0):

it was not the background you have to make 100%, its the `div` which you have to make 100%, for that there are many ways,

You can use absolute positioning. as @Hosney answered

```
.computer-middle-column{
    width: 600px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: green;
}
```