# Make vertical menu height fit 100%

Tags: html, css

I did a sketch https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiSi8.jpg so sidebar has to drag down all the way together with the content sidebar.

Comment: Can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642866/height-percentage-not-working-in-css

Answer (score 9, accepted):

its height should be 100% as well as all of its parents divs

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.sidebar{
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background:gray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahmedskaya/Bek9L/1863/

Comment: What if `.content` is heigher than 100%? this should be better : http://jsfiddle.net/Bek9L/1879/

Answer (score 0):

Using a jquery you can achieve it easily.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#side").height( $("#main").height() );
});
```

Here is CSS also.

```
#side{background: gold;}
#side, #main{float:left; width:200px;}
```

Here is the ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/zifazeti/1/)***.