# CSS - make menu the size of the page

Tags: css

I have a vertical and extensible menu component within my page.

I want it to:

1.Occupy 100% of the screen's height.

2.Enable scrolling rather than extending underneath the screen.

for now, I am using the following CSS:

```
#enableScrolling {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

However, the list extends underneath the screen instead of allowing scrolling.
Therefore, using `height: 100%;` doesn't seem to work.

How should I do this correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make vertical menu height fit 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654776/make-vertical-menu-height-fit-100)

Comment: You might need to provide additional CSS/HTML for us to help debug the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

You can either make the menu the size of the view port using the `viewport height` style

## Solution 1

```
#enableScrolling{
height:100vh;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtzbd3b7/1/)** Try scrolling the red, then begin scrolling in the blue. You will see that the red box is only as high as the window.

Or you can `position` it `absolute` to make it the height of the entire website like this:

## Solution 2

```
#enableScrolling{
position:absolute;
top:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

With this second **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtzbd3b7/2/)** you can see that the red will take 100% height of the page, try scrolling the red, then scroll the blue. The red will never leave the viewport.

## Solution 3 (modified off Solution 1)

If the element is not already at the top

You can apply some `positioning` to help move your element to the top, in the same way it works for answer 2.

```
#enableScrolling{
position:absolute;
/*position at top*/
top:0;
/*position at left*/
left:0;
height:100vh;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: With the first one you still need absolute positioning at top: 0, wouldn't you?

Comment: Only if it wasn't at the top to begin with, I've added a JS Fiddle of it being the only element but still taking up the viewport, without touching the `positioning`.

Comment: Yeah, but the OP didn't specify, or provide any HTML.

Comment: ...Then how can he be mad about an answer? I gave him two simple solutions, both will work. The job of S/O isn't exactly to do the code for someone, it's to help them understand how something works using the answer you give them. In my fiddle of the first one, I demonstrated that it stays at the top, since it's already there. If this doesn't fit his need, there is nothing stopping him from doing some problem solving of his own to make it work for his need.

That being said, updating the answer to include the possible case where it is not at the top to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

**CSS**

```
#enableScrolling {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you specify

top: 0

Also it needs to be a positioning that will handle that so use

position: absolute

And then your answer would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use vh insteadt of %.

vh means viewheight. It isn't the ultimate solution for all devices and browser but works better than %.

```
#enableScrolling {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
```