# CSS Assigning div to any percent ends up filling the entire screen?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, height, percentage

I have this very simple div container and whenever I assign it's height to any percent it displays the entire divs content without any overflow?  Works when assigned to a set pixel value;
Working code but static:

```
.rounds-left{
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[image: Working Code but Static]

Code that refuses to work and gives weird bug

```
.rounds-left{
  height: 50%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[image: Code that doesn't work (can scroll down page to see rest of div)]

Comment: Stab in the dark: Probably because the parent element's height is ambiguous.

Comment: Just set the parents height as 100%, and it still gives me that bug, but thank you fro the suggestion :)

Comment: That would also be ambiguous, unless the parent of that element had either a fixed height or was the root element.

Comment: It was the root of the element

Comment: "root element" here meaning `<html>`.

Comment: Possible dupe: [CSS Assigning div to any percent ends up filling the entire screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642866/height-percentage-not-working-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the `height` of the parent, because if you are using `%`, then it is relative to something. Therefore here the `50%` has to be relative to some already defined `height`, so simply add do this:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

#### snippet with your code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: red
}
.rounds-left {
  height: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="rounds-left">

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
    normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem
    ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: have you tested my snippet? because it works there!!! If  it is not working in your code then i need to see it to help you better