# Set parent's (undefined width and height) dimension equal to child's

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a parent div with undefined width or height.

The first child 'a' has set width and height. How can I make the parent have the size dimensions as the child.

```css
.parent{
    position: fixed;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}

.child-a{
  position:absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height:50px;
  background: red;
}

.child-b{ 
  width:100%;
  height:120%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-a'></div>
  <div class='child-b'></div>
</div>
```

2nd part: I want the div 'c' to be 120% of the parent's height, and be positioned behind div 'a'. So only the bottom of 'c' is visible.

I've tried multiple solutions include `display: table`, `overflow: overlay` etc but nothing gives me the desired result. I'm looking for a **CSS only solution**.

Comment: I would use javascript for the 2nd part, having a function to calculate 120% of the parent's height. If you want I can post that as an answer...

Comment: Would [Sass variables](http://sass-lang.com/guide) work for you? Using calc( parentDimensions ) you could achieve what you're asking, possibly. Can you elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
function childSize () {
 var parentHeight = document.getElementById( HAVE PARENTS ID HERE ).offsetHeight;
 parentHeight = parentHeight / 100 * 120;

 document.getElementById( HAVE CHILD C ID HERE ).offsetHeight = parentHeight;
}
```

This answer is only for the second part hope it helps :)

Comment: I should've mentioned I'm looking for CSS only solutions. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

For `height` percentage to work, its parent has to have a height property too. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16642908/5599288 . Therefore, the parent's height cannot be undefined or automatically sized.

You gotta set a fixed height on the parent, then control the child using percentage. This is how i would do it, in a pure CSS way,

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/jZrvWw

```
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

.child-a {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  // set size, padding 10px and centering
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.child-b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  background: blue;
}
```